# Issues with ToDate and MonthsBetween function in pig latin

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to calculate number of months between two datetime objects with the following code.

abc = load '/tmp/abc_2013_06_29/*' using PigStorage('\u0001') as ( open_dte: datetime,  clsd_dte: datetime);

duration_in_months = MonthsBetween(open_dte, clsd_dte);

I am trying to generate the relation duration_in_months in another relation. However I am facing the following error,

Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.GetMonth as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Appreciate any your help and also of any in-depth guide for learning casting and functions in pig.

Thanks,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not look correct. 
Try instead

```
duration_in_months = FOREACH abc GENERATE MonthsBetween(open_dte, clsd_dte);
```